# react router with negative lookahead

Tags: react-router

Basically I am trying to catch `<Route path="/:slug" />` but other than `/not-found`.
I try to use path-to-regex's Custom Match Parameters that looks like `/:slug(^(?!.*not-found).*$)` but it doesn't work.
It does not work here http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/, but it does work in https://regex101.com/

I am wondering how can I exclude a path when I am trying to catch `/:slug`?

Answer (score 5):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/99) in path-to-regex repo saying this is not supported, but using RegEx is. However react-router only support path as string [currently](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4551).

Also, you can test path-to-regex matching in [this demo](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)

So to get this behaviour I think the way to go is to look at the `match` or `location` props of the component render by `<Route path="/:slug" />` and conditionally render a not-found component.