# react-router render menu when path does not match

Tags: react-router

I'm using react-router and I want to render a menu component when the user is **not in** the root and not in the /login path.  This is what I have so far

```
        <Route path="/:subpath" component={TopMenuComponent} />
        <div>
            <Route
                exact path="/"
                render={props => (
                    <LoginContainer {...props} setTitle={this.setTitle} />
                )}
            />               
            <Route path='/landing' component={LandingComponent} />
        </div>
```

takes care of not rendering the TopMenuComponent component in the '/' location, however how do I avoid it rendering TopMenuComponent when the user is in the /login path?  I could always create another component and wrap it up, but I think that is too much just for this.

Comment: You could try a embedding your `TopMenuComponent` within a ternary operator that only shows it when the `path` does not equal `'/'` or `'/login'`.

Comment: but this is too much, upon further reading I found the following https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string, so I need something which path-to-regexp understands

Comment: Even better. Try: `^(?!.*(/|/login)).*$`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### **Simplest Implementation**

Use a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) or [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) to conditionally render your component based on `location.pathname`, like so:

```
<Route 
    render={({ location }) => ['/', '/login'].includes(location.pathname)
        ? <Component/>
        : null
    }
/>
```

### **Regex Implementation**

React Router's matching of [`path strings`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) relies on [`path-to-regexp@^1.7.0`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0).

As a result, you can instruct `routes` to not render for certain paths using [`regular expressions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The following implementations should render given any `path` value, bar `"/"` and `"/login"`:

```
// With Regex Inside String.
<Route path={"^(?!.*(\/|\/login)).*$"} component={TopMenuComponent}/>

// With Explicit Regex.
<Route path={new RegExp('^(?!.*(\/|\/login)).*$')} component={TopMenuComponent}/>
```

Comment: For me passing a regex with negative look-aheads did not work if I tried to pass it as a string, but does work if I pass it as a RegExp object like this: 
`<Route path={ new RegExp("^(?!.*(/|/login)).*$") } component={TopMenuComponent}/>`

Comment: Neither this nor @vladvlad's solution is possible. See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44516325/1058033

Comment: [`path: string | string[]` - "Any valid **URL path** or **array of paths** that **path-to-regexp@^1.7.0** understands"](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) @vladvlad @vitaliygorbenko

Comment: if this isn't working for you try escaping the slashes ```^(?!.*(\/|\/login)).*$"```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/99

Answer (score 9):

Regex in the route path didn't work for me. What worked for me was this. Just add the other condition.

```
 <Route render={({ location }) => {
     return location.pathname.indexOf('/login') === -1 ? TopMenuComponent : null 
  }} />
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't wish to use Regular Expressions directly, you can place your login `Route` in a `Switch` with the top menu component `Route`. It will only run the first matching `Route` and routes without a path attribute match anything.

```
<div>
    <Switch>
      <Route
          exact path="/"
          render={props => (
              <LoginContainer {...props} setTitle={this.setTitle} />
          )}
      />
      <Route path="/:subpath" component={TopMenuComponent} />
    </Switch>           
    <Route path='/landing' component={LandingComponent} />
</div>
```

For your example, you would need to reorder your divs.

Answer (score 4):

Taken Regex from [Arman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5566355/arman-charan)'s answer.

```
const notInLogin = /^(?!.*(\/login)).*$/

export default () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <>
      <Route path={notInLogin} component={NavBar} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/accounts" component={Account} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  </Router>
)
```

If you get PropsType error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439120/1099314

Answer (score 3):

Similar to taylor michels answer, but the following accounts for both the '/login' and the '/' (root) routes:

```
<Route
   render={({ location }) =>
     location.pathname !== "/" && location.pathname !== "/login" ? (
       <TopMenuComponent />
     ) : null
   }
 />>
```

This also renders the component as a jsx tag `<TopMenuComponent />`, which works for me where the other approach did not.

Comment: Same... required JSX `<TopMenuComponent/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**useRouteMatch** hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

```
const ParentComponent = props => {
  const matched = useRouteMatch(['/', '/login'])
  
  if (matched && matched.isExact) return null

  return <ChildComponent {...props} />
}
```

Comment: That page doesn't exist anymore. Or not with the current version.