# Why does react-router treat a regex `path` correctly, but throws an error at the same time?

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router

I have a component that I want to be displayed on all the paths except for root path. So instead of providing all the paths to the `Route` component, I wrote this:

```
<Route exact path={/^\/.+$/} component={() =>
  <div><img src="../../../assets/AndreyBogdanov2.jpg" className="me" /></div>
} />
```

That regex matches all the strings that have any character after the slash in the beginning. And it works as expected, however, in the console I see an error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` of type `regexp` supplied to `Route`, expected `string`.
    in Route (created by App)
    in App
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
```

Not that I'm complaining, but I would like to know, how come it works?

In the docs for the `path` prop it says that it needs to be any URL that `path-to-regexp` understands, and in the `path-to-regexp`'s docs, it says that regex is a valid parameter. So basically, it's the component's `PropTypes` that throws the error when it encounters something other than a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because the only thing `Route` does is to pass the object to `path-to-regexp`, which does support `RegExp` instances.

`PropTypes` based validation throws warnings, but doesn't stop the properties from actually being handled.

In this case this is probably a bug. `PropType` for `path` is not written correctly to match the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

It is because it can only accept a string value. You also need to insert something that `path-to-regexp` can read as described in [React Router Training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/path-string). You can look for how to write valid regexes in their repository [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp).

Comment: NP  ! Thanks for contributing to the community, and being a positive influence.