# How to render a component only for one Route?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to remove **Header** component from route page only . How can i do this in React router 4 ?

this is my Routes

```
const AppRouter: any = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path={LOOP_MAIN_ROUTE} component={LandingPage} exact/>
            <Route path={LOOP_LOGIN_ROUTE} component={LoginPage} exact/>
            <ProtectedRoute path={LOOP_SEARCH_ROUTE} component={SearchPage} />
            <ProtectedRoute path={LOOP_OFFER_ROUTE} component={Offer} exact />
            <ProtectedRoute path={LOOP_OFFER_APPROVAL} component={OfferApproval} exact />
            <ProtectedRoute path={LOOP_OFFER_CONFIRMATION} component={OfferConfirmation} exact />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: for what path `Header` should render?

Comment: there is no path ... First i have tried to render it for all routes , but now i need to NOT render for LOOP_MAIN_ROUTE

Comment: you can pass a regex, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46824062/3148807) it may help

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Consider updating the question with this information because the question says the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using [matchPath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath). For instance in your Header component:

```
import React from "react";
import {LOOP_MAIN_ROUTE} from "whereverYouHaveThisConstant";
import { withRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';
const Header = (props) => {
   const suppressHeader = matchPath(props.location.pathname, {path: LOOP_MAIN_ROUTE});
   if (suppressHeader ) {
      return null;
   }
   return <>your header stuff</>;
};
export default withRouter(Header);
```

Comment: This works fine , only i change the  suppressHeader whit **suppressHeader.isExact**

Answer (score 2):

`Header` can be conditionally rendered as a route:

```
<Route render={
  ({ location: { pathname } }) => pathname !== LOOP_MAIN_ROUTE && <Header/>
}/>
```

Comment: I think this is more elegant solution