# How to fix 'SyntaxError: invalid regular expression' in React Router regex path

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router

I am building a single page React app in ReactJS using react-router, and want to show a certain component only when in root (path="/"). To do this I am trying to use regex in the Route path. However, this either throws a SyntaxError or just simply doesn't work.

I managed to create two different regular expressions that do what I want it to do on www.regex101.com. They don't work when I put them in my React code though.

I used this Stack Overflow as an example: [react-router render menu when path does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823112/react-router-render-menu-when-path-does-not-match)
and looked at many others trying to solve the problem, but I can't figure out what goes wrong and how to fix it.

The first option I tried is:

```
<Router>
   <Route path="(?![\/]$).+" component={BackBtn} />
</Router>
```

This throws the following error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/^((?:?\![\\/]\$))\.\+(?:\/(?=$))?(?=\/|$)/`: Nothing to repeat

The other option I tried is:

```
<Router>
   <Route path="[\/]+[a-z]+" component={BackBtn} />
</Router>
```

This doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't show my BackBtn component when I'm not on the root page (e.g. path="/project")

What I expect it to do, is to HIDE the BackBtn component when the path is '/' but to SHOW the component when the path is for example '/project' or '/about' or '/contact'. Whenever the user clicks on the BackBtn component, the user is redirected back to root and thus the BackBtn component should be hidden again. 
So:
SHOULD MATCH:
/project
/about
/contact
SHOULD NOT MATCH:
/

How can I change my regular expression so that it hides BackBtn component when the path is '/', but shows the component for all other paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route), it doesn't look like the `path` prop accepts regular expressions. The comments on the accepted answer on the question you linked to seem to back that up as well. 
If your only routes are /project, /about, and /contact, it looks like you can use an array of routes in `path`, like this:

`<Route path={['/project', '/about', '/contact']} component={BackBtn} />`.

Otherwise, you could try using the [React Router Switch component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) and have a Route component that looks for the `/` path and renders nothing on it, and then another default Route that renders the back button on all other routes. Something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={null} />
  <Route component={BackButton} />
</Switch>
```