# React-router-dom how to update parent state inside route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a class parent class App containing a navbar and a bunch of routes:

```
function App() {
    const [showNavbar, setShowNavbar] = useState(true);

    return (
        <>

            <MyNavBar show={showNavbar}/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/child' component={() => <ChildPart setter={showNavbar}/>}/>
                <Route> ... //other routes
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
function ChildPart(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");

    // hide navbar
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("child init"); // this got printed twice


        props.setter(false);
    }, [props.setter]);

    // get data at first mount;
    useEffect(()=>{
        setData(api.loadUserInfo());

    }, []);

    return (<div>
        Data here: {data}
    </div>)
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have navbar change based on which page a user is currently at.
For example, hide navbar when use is visiting `/child`

But by implementing it this way, the ChildPart seems got mount and unmount for twice since the parent is rendered and rotues are also a part of the App.

This causes unnecessary API calls inside the child component.

Is there any way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hiding one (MyNavBar) component by navigating to one (or more) urls is a goal, something like [this could work](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mccarthy-pfw78). Unfortunatelly negative lookup (regex) [is not supported by react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514510/react-router-with-negative-lookahead) so we can't use something like this `(?!child)`.

Another thing which you can do is making `MyNavBar` aware of current url by wrapping it `withRouter` HOC or using `useLocation` hook. Than, you can do your logic in `MyNavBar` depending on url.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered adding the Navbar as a component in the Routes, instead of using the state to decide if the navbar should be visible or not?

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/child' component={ChildPart}/> 
    <Route path="">
         <MyNavBar />
         <Home />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely is a solution. However, the real situation might be more complicated where other pages might want to preserve navbar's state (like user search inputs in a search box) after the child component is rendered. So this might introduce extra work needed to coordinate the navbar's state between different pages.